# three data.table merge behavior inconsistency

Tags: r, data.table

I've been searching around this morning to try to figure out if the failure below is expected but haven't found anything. Could anyone help point me to a related discussion? Otherwise, I might [submit as an issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues). Appreciate it.

```
library(data.table)

x <- data.table( a = 1:3 )
y <- data.table( a = 2:4 )
z <- data.table( a = 3:5 )

# works
merge( x , y )
# works
merge( y , z )

# fails
merge( x , merge( y , z ) )
# Error in merge.data.table(x, merge(y, z)) :
#   A non-empty vector of column names for `by` is required.

# works
merge( merge( x , y ) , z )
```

Comment: Looks like this error comes from `data.table` as it works with `data.frame`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a clear bug. Please report it. Luckily, it should be easy to fix.

`merge.data.table` contains this code:

```
if (is.null(by)) 
  by = intersect(key(x), key(y))
if (is.null(by)) 
  by = key(x)
if (is.null(by)) 
  by = intersect(names(x), names(y))
```

Now, the issue is that `y` is keyed (because `merge.data.table` sets a key):

```
x <- data.table( a = 1:3 )
y <- merge(data.table( a = 2:4 ), data.table( a = 3:5 ))
haskey(y)
#[1] TRUE
```

Then,

```
intersect(key(x), key(y))
#character(0)
```

Thus, none of the following `if` conditions is TRUE (we would want the third one to apply here).

This doesn't happen in your last case because of this:

```
intersect("foo", NULL)
#NULL
intersect(NULL, "foo")
#character(0)
```

Comment: thank you!  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4772